# Unable to set config in spark-submit from command line

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0, sparkcore

I am trying to set master URL in the Application jar using below:

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .master("spark://master:7077")
  .appName("TestApp")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/tmp/spark-warehouse")
  .getOrCreate()
```

I try to run the jar with below parameters:

```
spark-submit -—num-executors 10 -—executor-memory 5G appJar.jar
```

spark-submit does not take the explict options provided to the jar. When the master URL is set in application jar, every other config is ignored? Can someone explain this please?

Comment: What's the character in front of `num-executors` and `executor-memory`? How do you check whether the options are taken into account or not?

Comment: In order to check the spark config you can try the following: logger.info("spark config: " + sparkConf.toDebugString());

Comment: @JacekLaskowski

below is what I did

`spark-submit SparkArgs.jar --master spark://sparkmaster:7077 --executor-memory 4G --num-executors 2`

I checked the Web UI:

`Cores: Unlimited (80 granted)`
`Executor Limit: Unlimited (5 granted)`
`Executor Memory: 1024.0 MB`

My code was pretty simple:

    `val spark = SparkSession.builder().master(masterURL).appName("Test Spark Args").getOrCreate()
    println("Application id: " + spark.sparkContext.applicationId)
    spark.stop()`

Comment: In the second test, below is my code:
Note, that I am not setting master in the code but I will pass it while running the jar


    `val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Test Spark Args").getOrCreate()
    spark.stop()`



    `spark-submit SparkArgs.jar --master spark://sparkmaster:7077 --executor-memory 4G --num-executors 2`

Below is the snapshot from Spark UI. If you see this, executor memory is overwritten.

`Cores: Unlimited (80 granted)`
`Executor Limit: Unlimited (5 granted)`
`Executor Memory: 4.0 GB`

Answer (score 2):

I think correct way is to give --

```
spark-submit --num-executors 10 --executor-memory 5G appJar.jar
```